# Problem using PlotMarkers -> "Sphere" in a DiscretePlot3D

Tags: plotting

I am trying to make a DiscretePlot3D of a DiscreteUniformDistribution but the result in not the expected.
I tried to use the PlotMarker-> "Sphere" but the spheres appear flattened. With other distributions this does not happens.

The code was the following

```
DiscretePlot3D[
 PDF[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{{1, 6}, {1, 6}}], {x, y}], {x, 1, 6}, {y, 1, 6},
 PlotMarkers -> {"Sphere", Large},
 PlotStyle -> Thick
 ]
```

[image]

I don't know why this happens. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect this is a bug.

Note:

```
DiscretePlot3D[
 PDF[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{{1, 6}, {1, 6}}], {x, y}], {x, 0, 
  6}, {y, 0, 6}, PlotMarkers -> {"Sphere", Large}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.5, 6.5}, {0.5, 6.5}, {0, .04}}]
```

[image]

Yet:

```
DiscretePlot3D[
 PDF[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{{1, 6}, {1, 6}}], {x, y}], {x, 1, 
  6}, {y, 1, 6}, PlotMarkers -> {"Sphere", Large}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.5, 6.5}, {0.5, 6.5}, {0, .04}}]
```

[image]

In both cases, the "aspect/box ratio of the plot" is the same, and "The z axis is very narrow", putting paid I think to that being the cause.

I see the same behavior on 11.x and 12.x, BTW.

Comment: the upper plot range limit  must be larger than the upper distribution limit to get the sphere shape.